# multiple forms using php

Tags: php, forms

I am trying to create three forms. I want them to go in a certain order. However instead they the first one is appearing by itself but the second and the third form are connected to each other. Although they are submitting three times. How do I get it so that each forms comes out individually? Here is my php

```
 <?php if ($_POST['token'] == "2" && "3") { ?>
 <h1>Approval Decision Submited.</h1>

 <?php } else if ($_POST['token'] == "1" && "2") {
echo "<h1>Form has been submitted</h1>";
} else {

if (isset($_GET['uid']) && isset($records)){

?>
```

Comment: You have three differents `<form></form>` inside your page and you want to differ them inside your PHP script ?

Comment: I don't understand your question and your code doesn't make sense.

Comment: "3" is true try $_POST['token']=2 OR $_POST['token']=3

Comment: What does your code have to do with 3 `<form>`s?

Comment: Why is `'2'` in both the `if` and the `else if`?

Comment: I am trying to create three forms. First it is filled out then submitted to the manager then the manager gets an email. which directs him to another form. he fills it out and it sent to the client and the client in return resubmits it to the person who filled it out. So i want the message to respond to both the original user and the manager.

Answer (score 5):

This is likely not what you want:

```
$_POST['token'] == "2" && "3"
```

It doesn't make sense either like this:

```
($_POST['token'] == "2") && "3"
```

Or like this:

```
$_POST['token'] == ("2" && "3")
```

I'm guessing you want this:

```
$_POST['token'] == "2" || $_POST['token'] == 3
```

Comment: you type so much faster than I do :P

Comment: hmm..its still not working tho. I cant seem to separate the third form from the second one.

Answer (score 0):

One major issue is the way you're using `&&`. `if ($_POST['token'] == "2" && "3")` will be evaluated as:

```
$_POST['token'] == 2   // true if it's equal to 2
AND
3    // a nonzero number is always true
```

So the conditional will evaluate true whenever `token` is 2.

If you wrote `$_POST['token'] == 2 && $_POST['token'] == 3` then it would never be true, since `token` can be 2 or 3, but not both at the same time.

If you want it to be true when `token` is either 2 or 3, use `||` instead of `&&`.